How can I get the weight function of the differential eqaution based on Sturm-Liouvile theorem?
I have derived a differential equation
$(4x^4-2x^2+4x)y+(4x^3+6x)y'+(x^4+x^2)y''=2x^2\cdots(1)$
The solution of this equation is closely related to the square of spherical Hankel function.
$y_p=C_1(h_1^{(1)}(x))^2+C_2(h_1^{(1)}(x))^2\cdots(2)$
$y_t=\frac{x^4}{x^2+1}\cdots(3)$
$y=C_1(h_1^{(1)}(x))^2+C_2(h_1^{(1)}(x))^2+\frac{x^4}{x^2+1}\cdots(2)+(3)$
And I transformed the equation (1) into Sturm-Liouvile form.
$[\frac{x^6y'}{x^2+1}]'+\frac{2x^4(2x^4-x^2+2)}{(x^2+1)^2}y=\frac{2x^6}{(x^2+1)^2}\cdots(4)$
This is all I have done, and what I want is finding the weight function and Eigenvalues.
What I intended was finding weight function for the square of the spherical Bessel function.
The solution of the equation becomes the square of the spherical Bessel function when C1=C2=1/2
And this is the only solution that has meets the boudary condition, as far as I know, which is,
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} y(x) = 0$
The general form of the Sturm-Liouvile equation is the following.
$\frac{d}{dx}[P(x)\frac{dy}{dx}]+Q(x)y=-\lambda \omega (x)y + f(x)\cdots(5)$
But it seems that equation (4) has the following form.
$\frac{d}{dx}[P(x)\frac{dy}{dx}]+Q(x)y=f(x)\cdots(6)$
What can I do to get the weight function?
